# Image not loading on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

i'm trying to load an image onto a canvas and hasn't been working after trying everything...

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var start = new Image();

start.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(start, 0, 0, start.width, start.height, 0, 0, 
     canvas.width, canvas.height);
     }

start.src = "hangman0.png";
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code, as I am trying to draw this image and then scale is to the canvas' width and height, but the picture just isn't showing up no matter what. Any pointers? I've tried changing both my HTML5 and css code, still no avail.

CSS:

```
canvas{
     background-color: rgb(0,198,255);
     border-style: ridge;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-color: rgb(157,255,0);
     position: relative;
}
```

HTML5:

```
<body>
   <div id='section'>
      <canvas id='myCanvas' width='979px' height='560px'></canvas>
      <script src="projectJavaScript.js"></script>
   </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your offered code works for me as long as I use `window.onload`:

Are you wrapping `script` code inside `window.onload`?

```
<script>
window.onload=(function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var start = new Image();

    start.onload = function(){
         context.drawImage(start, 0, 0, start.width, start.height, 0, 0, 
         canvas.width, canvas.height);
         }

    start.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/rainy.png";

}); // end window.onload
</script>
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

*Note: StackSnippets automatically wrap JS-script code inside window.onload*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var start = new Image();

start.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(start, 0, 0, start.width, start.height, 0, 0, 
     canvas.width, canvas.height);
     }

start.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/rainy.png";
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='979px' height='560px'></canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm not very good with some JS terms as i'm fairly new to this, what do you mean by wrapping script code inside window.onload? My javascript code is in its own file, and i'm calling the script from the HTML file. I also tried your code, still doesn't draw anything :(

Comment: "Wrap" means put your code inside something -- in this case it means put your code inside a function [`function(){ YOUR-CODE }`] that waits for the browser to load your window before it tries to execute your JS. So, in your external JS file, put `window.onload=(function(){` at the top and `})` at the bottom. :-)

Comment: I did the wrapping now, but it's kinda glitching my whole page now, it's drawing the picture I want but keeps flashing the whole page white, and my page doesn't finish loading i.e. the loading circle keeps running. But at least it's doing something compared to before when it doesn't change at all, thank you very much! I'll try and solve this glitch first.

Answer (score -1):

You appear to be setting the image source after it is used which would been it would be using the default blank state when it is called.

You also appear to be using start.onload but start is not element but varble that represents one, it not going to be loaded since it not part of original html elements. I would use canvas.onload or run it with body.onload